# How to get image from firebase-storage in ionic 3

Tags: angular, ionic3, firebase-storage

Here is my storage (set manually in firebase ) who contain bottle photo.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/56Dta.png

here is my Database (bottle with several properties) but without his picture

https://i.stack.imgur.com/j1eBS.png

My questions are,

how to get my bottle photo by storage (firebase-storage doc didn't help me) ? 
do I proceed correctly ?

thanks for reading me !

Answer (score 2):

You first need to create a Cloud Storage reference. There are multiple ways:

with an initial file path and name

```
var storage = firebase.storage();
var pathReference = storage.ref('images/stars.jpg');
```

Or from a Google Cloud Storage URI

```
var gsReference = storage.refFromURL('gs://bucket/images/stars.jpg')
```

Or from an HTTPS URL

```
var httpsReference = storage.refFromURL('https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/b/bucket/o/images%20stars.jpg');
```

Once you have the reference, you can get the download URL for a file by calling the getDownloadURL() method on a storage reference.

```
storageRef.child('images/stars.jpg').getDownloadURL().then(function(url) {
  // `url` is the download URL for 'images/stars.jpg'

  // This can be downloaded directly:
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.responseType = 'blob';
  xhr.onload = function(event) {
    var blob = xhr.response;
  };
  xhr.open('GET', url);
  xhr.send();

  // Or inserted into an <img> element:
  var img = document.getElementById('myimg');
  img.src = url;
}).catch(function(error) {
  // Handle any errors
});
```

More details [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/download-files)

Comment: http://img110.xooimage.com/files/0/8/d/test-542267a.png import is bad ?

Comment: not ionic storage, use firebase storage: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.storage